# How do I make a custom project-template show me a certain view on creating a new project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I create a new project of the predefined templates, say a new windows form application – it starts out showing me the designer view of Form1.

What I want to do is something similar with the custom template. (Actually, I want the code-view.) Currently, nothing is shown automatically.

I created the project with “Export template”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your template zip file and in file *.vstemplate add attribute OpenInEditor="true" to code files you would like to open on project creation ([ProjectItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys81cc94.aspx)). i tried to open code for Form and i failed, but it works pretty well for simple code files.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be what I was looking for. However – I wasn’t successful in getting it to work. I added the `OpenInEditor` in both “Templates” and “My Exported Templates”. But when I tried to save it – even though I chose the “overwrite” option – it didn’t save it (though it didn’t give me any error message). When opening it again – the new line wasn’t there. Any ideas?

Comment: on my computer i edited templates located in 'Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates' i had same issues with saving, i just moved zip to desktop edited, packed to zip and moved bacedk to ProjectTemplates folder